# Web login using windows credentials

Tags: windows, sharepoint, authentication, ldap, kerberos

We have an intranet site on our corporate network (SharePoint 3). If I look at it via Internet Explorer - I'm already logged in. If I look at it using Firefox I have to enter my windows username & password.

My questions is this:

Why is there this discrepancy between the browsers? Does Microsoft have some proprietary plugin in IE that can enable this auto login? Can I achieve auto-login in Firefox?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you have two questions please ask them as two separate questions. Your questions apply to different audiences so you'll get better answers and the voting/answer system will work as designed.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've split the Perl question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227349/intranet-website-authentication-using-windows-logon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open Firefox and type “about:config” in the address bar.
2. In the ‘Filter’ field type the following “network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris”
3. Double click the name of the preference that we just searched for
4. Enter the URLs of the sites you wish to pass NTLM auth info to (comma separated)

This is the equivalent to adding the site to the Intranet zone in IE.

Comment: any ideas on how would you do this in an "automated way" to multiple computers in a network?

Comment: @nmuntz, AFAIK, FF doesn't have any  AD integration out of the box, but http://www.frontmotion.com/Firefox/ Frontmotion packages a AD version that may do what you want, I haven't used it

Answer (score 1):

This is because Firefox doesn't do a great job of supporting NTLM, also known as Windows Authentication. If you search for `firefox ntlm` you will find plenty of resources that give you options on how this can work.

I change workplaces every six months or so and have never been able to get this to work reliably. Sometimes it's flawless, other times I always get prompted no matter what. They are slowly improving the support with newer Firefox versions however, so you might like to try a complete uninstall and reinstall of Firefox as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, set the network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris option in about:config to a comma separated list of host names you want to NTLM with.

I'm not sure if there's a better way to trust all machines on the lan like in IE.