# Intranet website authentication using windows logon

Tags: windows, authentication, webserver, ntlm

I'm building an internal website in Perl and I would like to get it to use Windows credentials for authentication. My research so far has turned up a lot of keywords: Kerberos, LDAP, NTLM, etc, but no solid information. Anyone got pointers or good tutorials?

Thanks.

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your servers part of a Microsoft Active Directory?

- Active Directory is LDAP-compliant.  Therefore, you can setup LDAP to authenticate your users
- Are you using Apache?  If so, there is a module that allows you to authenticate to an Active Directory directory:  [mod_ auth_sspi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/)
- Finally, Microsoft has created Active Directory Service Interfaces (ASDI) to solve these types of problems.  There is a lot of information at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170(VS.85).aspx).  For example, this is how the open-source Hudson CI server authenticates to Active Directory.

I hope one of these suggestions help you.

Comment: I think we are using AD. Thanks very much for your pointers. I'm sure one of these ideas will be what I need.

Answer (score 3):

We've been using Mod NTML for Apache. It fetches the windows credentials of the user logged in. But you're probably not interested in the SSO?

http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I think SSO is what I'm after. I'm just trying to improve the user experience by reducing the number of passwords to remember & reduce the number of times credentials have to be entered.

Thanks for your tip, this many be exactly when I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking into this topic myself.  I'm still not sure what the right answer is because the topic is out of my domain of knowledge & experience.  But here are some possibilities that I've come up with by searching the Internet:

An Apache LDAP module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_ldap.html

A Perl Module for Apache LDAP authentication:  [Apache2::AuthNetLDAP](http://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2::AuthNetLDAP)

NT authentication using an Apache Perl Module:  [Apache2::AuthenSmb](http://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2::AuthenSmb)

Using NIS for Apache user authentication:  http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialApacheAddingLoginSiteProtection.html#NIS

An article describing ActiveDirectory authentication using Apache:  http://www.le.ac.uk/cc/sh23/adldap.html

An open source ActiveDirectory solution from a business:  http://www.likewise.com/

Answer (score 2):

For Tomcat on Windows you can use [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com), both SSO and form-based/basic/digest auth.

Comment: You also do not need to create a service principal provider in active directory to use this one.