# User Authentication using Windows logged in username in Java web application

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee

I want to authenticate user based on his username with which he is logged in in Windows.
Actually I am building a web application for my organisation , so I don't want login page if the login user is already registered with us.
The web application should automatically get username and match it with database and allow access.
System.getproperty("user.name") gives server username.
And there is no JavaScript code to get client machine username because of security reasons.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227349/intranet-website-authentication-using-windows-logon) might be relevant to you

Comment: Other alternatives may include looking at the IP of connecting computers, or forcing them to login once but then storing some sort of login token in their LocalStorage which you can use to keep them logged in